# Range of $x \mapsto\dfrac{e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x}+1}$

Tags: calculus, functions

I have the function

$$ x \mapsto \frac{e^{2x} - 1}{e^{2x}+1} $$

My method doesn't include logarithmic algebra. Instead I try to manipulate the numerator so in order to get $1 - \frac2{e^{2x}+1}$. Now I know that range of $e^{2x}+ 1$ which is $(2,\infty)$. But I don't know the steps to get range of Y. Can someone please explain what $1 - 2/(2,\infty)$ is ?

Comment: Y = e^2x - 1 / e^2x + 1 . What's wrong in this?

Comment: The range of $e^{2x}+ 1$ is not $(2,\infty).$ ...well, it depends on which domain.

Comment: Your "equation" is actually a *function*. And [a wellknown one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_functions#Hyperbolic_tangent).

Answer (score 3):

Put $u=e^{2x}$. Then $u\in(0,\infty)$. So you want the range of
$$\frac{u-1}{u+1}$$
over $(0,\infty)$. But this is just
$$1-\frac{2}{u+1}$$
What is the range of $\dfrac{1}{u+1}$ over $(0,\infty)$?

Answer (score 2):

Then a *slightly* another way .

---

$$
\begin{align}&\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}=y\\
\implies &e^{2x}=\frac {1+y}{1-y}>0,\thinspace \forall x\in\mathbb R\tag {1}\\
\implies &(1-y)(1+y)>0 \tag {2}\\
\implies &-1<y<1\thinspace .\end{align}
$$

---

$\rm\bf {Comments:}$

$(1)\thinspace \thinspace $ $e^{2x}>0,\thinspace\forall x\in\mathbb R\thinspace $ means : $e^{2x}$ is always *positive*,  for all $x\in\mathbb R\thinspace .$

$(2)\thinspace \thinspace $ Recall that, we have the following equivalence relation :

$$
\begin{align}A\cdot\frac 1B&=\frac AB>0\iff AB>0
\end{align}
$$

Because, you know that if $B≠0$, then :

$$
\begin{align}\operatorname {sgn}\left(B\right)=\operatorname {sgn}\left(\frac 1B\right)\end{align}
$$

where, $\thinspace \operatorname {sgn} x$
simply denotes the sign of $x\thinspace $ ( see : [sign function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function) ) .

This justifies the answer .

Comment: This is way cooler way to do this. Thank you

Comment: @MrX I don't think so, but thank you and you are welcome .

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $\,c\in\Bbb R\;$ belongs to the range of that function, then

$$c=f(x)=\frac{e^{2x}-1}{e^{2x}+1}\implies(1-c)e^{2x}=c+1\implies e^{2x}=\frac{c+1}{1-c}$$

What value can't $\;c\;$ attain? What can you deduce from this and from the fact that the exponential function $\;x\to e^x\;$ is onto $\;(0,\infty)\;$ ?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Divide numerator and denominator  by $ e^x$ . Recognize the bounded asymptotes in a hyperbolic function.